# How to get UTC time offsets from a geolocation

Tags: datetime, geolocation, utc, iso8601, datetimeoffset

We can find some lists of the UTC time offsets, showing the difference in hours and minutes from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), from the westernmost (−12:00) to the easternmost (+14:00).

In general, we save datetime using [iso8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

However - [by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) - we just includes some countries and regions.
And it is not very accurate. For instance, `UTC+01:00` is for Paris, Rome, Stockholm, Tunis, even if those cities are not exactly on the same longitude...

I would like to be able to find the *true UTC time offset* from a geolocation, in order to have a local time based on the position of the sun in the sky.

I mean, instead of having `UTC+01:00` near the Eiffel Tower at the geolocation `48.858844300000001,2.2943506` I would prefer to have `UTC+01:13` for example.

How could we do, having a geolocation such as `48.352845300000001,40.9943506`, to get the *true UTC time offset*?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: What purpose would this serve?  Local time doesn't really work that way.  Have you read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)?  You might also be interested in [how to convert a geolocation to the proper IANA time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).

Comment: I want to have offsets that are 8-minute offset, for instance. More precise than time zones.

Comment: Sure, as long as you understand that people don't actually set their clocks that way anywhere in the world.  At least not in modern times.

Comment: This is tres-cool, but the idea doesn't map very well to the idea of a UTC offset. In particular, due of the [Analemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma), the offset changes throughout the year at a single location. I think you would want to use something like [Local Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) which is fixed for a given Longitude.

Comment: You should be able to derive local mean time as a UTC offset from Longitude (which is relative to Greenwich) fairly easily. It's: `localOffset = (location.longitude * 24.0 / 360.0)`. I think :-) You might need to do a sign change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of the phrase 'true UTC', but I understand what you are asking. You could calculate the longitude distance between the user's position and the closest UTC longitude line, and then use that to determine your fractional hour offset.

Comment: This is also the way I would do it. However should we use a range from -12 to +12 (because there's 24h in a day) or a more complicated range from -12 to +14? Personally I would go for the first way. What do you think?

Comment: Each hour is 15 degrees in longitude apart (360/24). 0 degree longitude (prime meridian) would be UTC+00:00. 15 degrees East would be UTC+01:00 and 15 degrees West would be UTC-01:00. I googled the coordinate centroid for Berlin, Germany. The longitude is 13.3833 degrees East. This would calculate to UTC+00:54. I believe what you are asking about maybe what is called solar time.